# Magento 2: create multiple contact form with different recipients

Tags: magento2, contact-form

I need to create multiple contact forms, with different recipients. 
The contact forms I want to create, has to have the same fields, nothing fancy.

I just need to create different simple contact forms, each of them, with a different recipient.

Or eventually, I just need ONE contact form with a dropdown, that basing on the selection, it will send to a particular recipient.

Please, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rewriting only the send email,

You have to create another template html for the admin in order to receive the email and then rewrite the Controller.

Updated Answer.

Comment: Really? I thought it wasn't that complicated. Since I just need to use different recipients, but same form, I thought I just had to rewrite the sendMail(). Is that right?

Comment: If you want to send multiple recipients then it is easy, but if you want multiple form then it is too much complicated.

Comment: why? Can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: It was just a little more complicated than what I thought but I did it. Instead of rewriting only the sendemail, I had to create another template html for the admin in order to receive the email and then rewrite the Controller.

Comment: Okay!! Thanx, I have updated the Answer, If you want to edit or correct it, you can.